# VMWare guest connectivity goes down when VMWare host has VPN client connected

Tags: networking, vpn, vmware

I am having difficulties to make the following setup work :

I have two custom services running, one on my **VMWare host (MacOs)** and one on my **VMWare guest (Win10)**. Both services require to talk to each other AND both require to connect to a 3rd service accessible via a corporate VPN. This VPN client running on the VMWare host.

My two local service can talk to each - **only if** - VPN is off ( whether VMWare is using NAT or Bridge connection I can make both case work )

The issue arises as soon as my *Pulse Juniper VPN* client is on. At this point my VMWare guest seems to have no more connectivity whether traffic is inbound or outbound !

Is there some sort of incompatible setup between VMWare and Juniper Pulse tools ? I am novice with both tools and don't know how to move forward from there.. Any hints ?

Thanks

Comment: Check which IP ranges you're using for your internal network, they might be conflicting with the corporate network. In addition, depending on the corporation, maybe your whole traffic is routed through the corporate network?

Comment: Are you referring to the ranges in the vmware's dhcpd.conf file ? If so, they are different from the corporate network ( 192.168.* vs 10.220.* ).